# Correct term for describing how “interesting” a stock is to buy

Tags: single-word-requests

When I decide what stocks to place in my portfolio I do a series of technical and fundamental analyses and during each one I give stocks different numbers of "points", and I basically go for the ones which I've given the highest rating in the end. What I'm wondering is, is there some term for this rating? Stockbrokers probably have some kind of word for it?

The main reason why I'm asking this is that I'm programming an automating app for this process and I really can't think of anything good to name the variable.

Comment: You probably want "sentiment" or "rating". That's what Morningstar et al do.

Answer (score 2):

Name it after yourself: the Clox Rating or cloxrating... that's good enough and it works!

Comment: Or possibly Cox Ranking.

Comment: In a JavaScript command, probably as one word: "cloxranking" or the suggested "coxranking" similar to "cockranking."

Comment: Thanks for the one-word suggestion. I don't know JavaScript from BaklavaScript. I'd stay away from the "cockranking," however; it could go in an undesirable direction (viz., a porn direction!). Don

Comment: @rhetorician: the poster says, "I'm programming an automating app for this process and I really can't think of anything good to name the variable." JavaScript or the other variants will require a one-word (lowercase) 'noun'. The one-word conceptual 'noun'--"cockranking" might mean a ranking for fighting roosters. Yea, that's what I meant.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the mini-tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

You want the word **score**.

As an example, there is the Piotroski Score, which is described on [this page](http://www.grahaminvestor.com/articles/quantitative-tools/the-piotroski-score/):

> Piotroski devised a simple nine-criteria stock-scoring system for evaluating a stock’s financial strength that could be determined using data solely from financial statements.
>
> One point was awarded for each test that a stock passed. Piotroski classed any stocks that scored eight or nine points as being the strongest stocks. His findings were that these strong stocks as a group outperformed a portfolio of all value stocks by 7.5% annually over a 20-year test period. Piotroski also found that weak stocks, scoring two points or fewer, were five times more likely to either go bankrupt or delist due to financial problems.

Your system is similar to that - you have a system with fundamental and technical criteria, and for each criterion, you give stocks points.  You could call your system the Clox Score.